# Scan other war files in Wildfly

Tags: wildfly

I want to create a war file which contains an endpoint to access json files. I want to provide these json files in seperated war files, so I am able to "hot enhance" this endpoint.

It should looking something like this:

- Main.war: contains endpoint logic, which returns all found json
  files. The war file scans all other war files for
  **ressources/jsonfiles** folder to get all json files
- Bla.war: includes folder **ressources/jsonfiles** by definition
- Blub.war:includes folder **ressources/jsonfiles** by definition

Is it possible to get this done with wildfly?

Answer (score 1):

You could use exploded managed deployments and update your json files with the cli ore the web console. Thus you would only need a single war file. 
http://wildfly.org/news/2017/09/08/Exploded-deployments/ for some example